# run two functions in parallel matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have this problem: I have one MATLAB function that performs anisotropic diffusion on a volume. For a medical volume it takes about 20 min to complete the execution. Now I want to use this function simultaneously on two different volumes so that the total execution time remains 20 min and not 40 min total using Matlab's Parallel Computing Toolbox.
I have a quadcore Macbook so in my thoughts one core should run one the first volume and the second core should run the second volume.

How can I do that?

The functions I want to run simultaneously are:

```
filt1=anisodiff3D(volume1);
filt2=anisodiff3D(volume2);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I know you asked about the parallel computing toolbox solution, but still: I often just start up a second instance of Matlab, which will run in parallel as well. Just to remind you; the parallel computing toolbox isn't always necessary.

Comment: I know the topic is one-year old, but I feel my question is worth a comment rather than a question in itself. I have four scripts to run in MATLAB, but, contrary to the question, I cannot index the argument as the names of the scripts have little in common. I would like to assign a specific job to a specific worker (1, 2, 3 or 4) on a local cluster (quadcore) I have the distcomp toolbox. My question is: is it possible or do I have to resort to starting four instances of MATLAB ? Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 4):

You first need to **create a pool of Matlab processes** and then use the **parfor** construct. I would do like this:

```
% Useful for operating on parfor
filt = [filt1, filt2];
vol = [volume1, volume2];

% Please note that these are separate processes and sharing data can be challengin
matlabpool(2); % or parpool(2);

% Parallelize the for loop using 2 workers
parfor i = 1 : 2
   filt(i) = anisodiff3D(vol(i));
end
```

Comment: `matlabpool` was removed in Matlab 2014a, for recent versions use `parpool`

Comment: @Daniel thanks. I added it as a comment to the code.

Comment: Well I did it but the this was the result: Elapsed time is 4049.721585 seconds. Does anyone know the reason why this happens?

Comment: How did you measure time? What was the time with no parallelism? Does your core has hyperthreading? It may be the case where the processes executed on 2 hyperthreads not on 2 physical distinct cores.

Comment: I measured it with a simple tic,toc command! With no parallelism it was 2880.723432 seconds... What does hyperthreading mean? How do I figure this out? The Default cluster in parallel computing is local.

Comment: My mac is a MacbookPro retina. 2,5GHz Intel Core i7 processor, 16GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Memory

Comment: It has HT. Check here what it means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading . Did you check how are the cores utilized during runs? Does it look like it's using 2 cores instead of one?

Comment: If I type maxNumCompThreads in Matlab it returns 4. Is it right?

Comment: Using `parfor` with local workers only speeds things up if your original algorithm wasn't being intrinsically multi-threaded by MATLAB. Your timings suggest that it was being multi-threaded already, so the only way you can make things go even faster is to take advantage of additional computational resources.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for MATLAB parallel computing toolbox (unless you have got it already). This allows you do multiply things at parallelly (like running two functions). The catch is the IPC between those functions. I believe things get more complicated when you have them communicating with each other. If that's not required, you can use parallel for loop aka PARFOR through that toolbox in order to run two (or more) funcs parallelly.